# How much extra fuel is needed to transport a 1kg object over a distance of 10,000 miles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, efficient-energy-use

I propose the scenario: a 1,300-kilogram, base weight, vehicle is carrying a 1-kilogram textbook with a 35% efficient engine over a distance of 10,000 miles. How much fuel is being burned to carry this textbook?

I'm asking because I'm curious how much energy and carbon emissions could be saved if people emptied their vehicles of unnecessary weight. If you have anything more to add to this topic that I might find useful or interesting to consider, please include.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: If the force (=gravity) is orthogonal to the direction of travel, no work is done. So we would need a friction model.

Comment: How fast is the vehicle traveling?  At 60 mph, approximately 1/2 of the resistance experienced by the auto is wind resistance and 1/2 is rolling resistance, obviously depending on the aerodynamic shape of the auto.  But more to the point, excess weight does indeed require more fuel consumption, so car manufacturers are always trying to reduce the weight of their cars in order to increase gas mileage.

Comment: @ACuriousMind thank you for the welcome. I apologize if this sounds off topic, I'm merely looking for a place to gain an understanding. I'm an art school graduate trying to make sense of the bigger problem of fuel waste due to unnecessary weight being lugged around in millions of cars. I will try the homework site next time I have such a question.

Comment: @DavidWhite Forgot about wind resistance. I guess I'm trying to gain an understanding using the average car, weight, engine efficiency, yada yada. I'm having trouble visualizing how much an effect has on real tangible fuel costs & amounts over a period of time (say, 10,000 miles)

Answer (score 3):

To a very crude first approximation, we could sweep everything under the carpet by saying the car expands $x$ amount of fuel in moving a mass of $M$, and then assume there's some linear relationship relating the two.  That is $x=kM$, then the fuel needed for carrying $(M+m)$ would be $x=k(M+m)$.  The ratio between the two fuel expenditures is then $\frac{M+m}{M}$.   In your case that is saying the car uses $0.08\%$ more fuel due to carrying around that textbook.

I would love to go into more detail, but unfortunately I left my $1~\text{kg}$ textbook on car fuel-efficiency at home today ;)